# How can I solve this trig exponential equation ??

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

> $$(\sin x)^{(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(1-\cos2x)}
> = 1$$

I tried taking $\log_2$ of both sides and I got:

$(\sin(x))^2\cdot(1-\cos(x))=1$

Is it correct? If it is, how should I continue?

Answer (score 4):

$[(\log_2(\sin(x)))^2+\log_2(1-\cos(2x))] \ln(\sin(x)) =0$

So, either $\ln(\sin(x))=0$ and $\sin(x)=1$, or

\begin{align}
(\log_2(\sin(x)))^2+\log_2(1-1+2\sin^2(x)) &=0 \\
(\log_2(\sin(x)))^2+\log_2(2\sin^2(x)) &= 0 \\
(\log_2(\sin(x)))^2+2\log_2(\sin(x))+1 &= 0
\end{align}

Let $m=\log_2(\sin(x))$, $\ldots$

\begin{align}
m^2+2m+1 &= 0 \\
(m+1)^2 &= 0 \\
m &= -1 \\
\sin(x) &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

So, the solutions are when $\sin(x)=1$ or when $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Use reference angles, and be cognizant about which angles work in the original equation. (For example, you can’t take a logarithm of a negative number over the reals.)

Comment: where did the ln come from?

Comment: I took the $\ln$ of the original equation on both sides, then used $\log$ rules. It really shouldn't matter what base logarithm you used in the first step because $a^0=1$ for all positive $a$.

Comment: Basically I took the $\ln$ of both sides, so the right side of the equation goes to $0$, and we can bring the left hand side exponent down, multiplied by $\ln(\sin(x))$. Because the product of the $\ln(\sin(x))$ and the exponent of the LHS is zero, one of them (either the exponent, or the $\ln$ of sine, must be zero. We then solve each case. The only other trick I used was expressing $\cos(2x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$

Comment: can you take log2 of both sides ?

Comment: Yes you can. You'll get the same expression as my first line, except, instead of the $\ln$ of sine, you'll get the $\log_2$ of sine.

Comment: And it won't change the result because if you say $\log_2(\sin(x))=0$, then you get $\sin(x)=1$, the same as if it were $\ln(\sin(x))$. You see, $e^0=2^0=a^0$, so it doesn't matter what the base of the logarithm is.

Comment: The only other critical rule we use is that $\log_a(x^y)=y\log_a(x)$

Comment: uhh... forgive my ignorance but im still confused... Shouldnt I get this:

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aqogkn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38214/discussion-between--and-therue).

Comment: ups... it is only now that i see my error : http://prntscr.com/aqohzq

Comment: Right so I suppose we don't need to continue it in chat. I would caution you however, that $\log_2(\sin^2(x))$ is not the same thing as $(\log_2(\sin(x)))^2$. Also note that $\log_2(1)=0$ because $2^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$(\sin x)^{(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(1-\cos(2x))}
= 1
$.

Then
either
$\sin(x) = 1$
or
$(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(1-\cos(2x))
= 0
$.

If
$\sin(x) = 1$,
then
$x = \pi(2k+1)$
where
$k$ is an integer.

If
$(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(1-\cos(2x))
= 0
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(1-\cos(2x))\\
&=(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(2\sin^2(x))\\
&=(\log_2 \sin x)^2+\log_2(2)+2\log_2(\sin(x))\\
&=v^2+\log_2(2)+2v
\qquad\text{where } v = \log_2(\sin(x))\\
&=v^2+2v+1-1+\log_2(2)\\
&=(v+1)^2+\log_2(2)-1\\
&=(v+1)^2
\qquad\text{since }\log_2(2) = 1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$v+1 = 0$
or
$\log_2(\sin(x))
= -1
$
or
$\sin(x)
=\frac12
$
or
$x
=2k\pi+\pi/6
$
and
$x
=2k\pi+5\pi/6
$
(as pointed out by egreg)
where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: Also $x=5\pi/6+2k\pi$

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Upvoted.